# How to detect mouse drag events on Canvas using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

This JavaFX app contains a Canvas object (black bkg) on the middle of the window and i'm trying to detect mouse input on that canvas. I've added a simple print to the console action in response to each mouse event just for testing. The below works:

```
cnv.setOnMouseClicked();
```

but the following are not working:

```
cnv.setOnMouseDragOver();
cnv.setOnMouseDragEntered();
cnv.setOnMouseDragReleased();
cnv.setOnMouseDragExited();
```

Doesn't matter how i click-and-drag the mouse, only mouse clicks are detected ("mouseClicked" appears on the console).

```
package javafxtest1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class JavaFXTest1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 640);
        Canvas cnv = new Canvas(scene.getWidth()-200,scene.getHeight()-200);
        root.getChildren().add(cnv);

        //Fill the canvas with a black bkg so we can know where it is
        GraphicsContext gc = cnv.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, cnv.getWidth(), cnv.getHeight());

        //set response to mouse events
        cnv.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("mouseClicked");
        });
        cnv.setOnMouseDragOver((MouseDragEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("mouseDragOver");
        });
        cnv.setOnMouseDragEntered((MouseDragEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("mouseDragEntered");
        });
        cnv.setOnMouseDragReleased((MouseDragEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("mouseDragReleased");
        });
        cnv.setOnMouseDragExited((MouseDragEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("mouseDragExited");
        });


        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Where is my mistake?

(I'm on Win 7 64 with NetBeans 8.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those event handlers are for platform supported drag and drop handling, which is initiated if you call `startDragAndDrop()` in a drag detected event. (They are also only fired under certain circumstances, such as when the dragboard is not empty.)

You should just use `setOnMouseDragged()` for regular mouse event handling.

See the "Dragging Gestures" section of the [`MouseEvent` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) for details of the different mouse drag modes and the events they support.